# How do I get two file names in a list from the xcode project - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, enumeration

So I imported a file called Sound1.m4a and Sound2.m4a, I want to get those two file names into an array, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to iterate through them and get them.

I tried doing it by going into all the directories in the resource path with enumeration, but it's not working right and not getting the the sound files I imported into the xcode project.

```
- (NSArray*)getSounds{ 
    NSFileManager * fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString * sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath];
    NSArray* directories = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:sourcePath error:NULL];
    NSMutableArray * sounds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [directories enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSString *filename = (NSString *)obj;
        NSString *extension = [[filename pathExtension] lowercaseString];
        if ([extension isEqualToString:@"m4a"]) {
            [sounds addObject:[sourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
        }
    }];
    return sounds;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at your project's "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase to make sure that the .m4a files are actually getting copied over to your app. You can also use either breakpoints or NSLogs to verify the values of your `directories` array and the `filename` and `extension` variables.

Comment: Why aren't you using the `- (NSString *)pathForResource:(NSString *)name
                       ofType:(NSString *)extension` method from `NSBundle` to get the paths of your 2 files?